# Errors when running "network.sh up" with Hyperledger Fabric Samples in test-network

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I met errors when setting up blockchain network(test network) using Hyperledger Fabric Sample. 
Actually, when I run the scripts ./network.sh up, the docker images start but immediately shut down. And I check the logs found some errors reported.
And here are my errors shown:

**1. when setting orderer：**

2020-06-01 06:43:02.784 UTC [orderer.common.server] loadLocalMSP -> PANI 004 Failed to setup local msp with config: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo

panic: Failed to setup local msp with config: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo

goroutine 1 [running]:

github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc000254dc0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)

/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x546

github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc00010e338, 0xc000094904, 0x1066d69, 0x29, 0xc00029f610, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)

/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0x100

github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(...)

/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159

github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(...)

/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74

github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.loadLocalMSP(0xc00019a480, 0xc00026fe50, 0x0)

/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:677 +0x314

github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()

/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:91 +0x232

main.main()

/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20

**2. when setting up peers:**

2020-06-01 06:43:02.778 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo

is there anyone that may be able to help solve the problems?

best regards

Comment: Ensure key material is getting generated during n/w start up. Carefully observe the logs, and correlate them with echo statements in SH files.

Comment: Hello, did you solve this problem? I have same issue as you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443043/keymaterial-not-found-in-signingidentityinfo

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not set the right PATH. Set the Correct path of Go in environment variable.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y golang-go make
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
make docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the peer cannot read (or find) valid keystore/signcert in MSP folder. Can you show MSP directory tree structure of error peer. Example:

```sh
organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com
├── msp
│   ├── IssuerPublicKey
│   ├── IssuerRevocationPublicKey
│   ├── cacerts
│   │   └── localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── keystore
│   │   └── d57bc7fae634a1e29b95d5c218272f0b504774667f49d568c67c132b7b368684_sk
│   ├── signcerts
│   │   └── cert.pem
│   └── user
└── tls
    ├── IssuerPublicKey
    ├── IssuerRevocationPublicKey
    ├── ca.crt
    ├── cacerts
    ├── keystore
    │   └── a123ac3f8767a1a5b7a6238d1043e20edd7834f31e2e9352d8b8009b9c8005cf_sk
    ├── server.crt
    ├── server.key
    ├── signcerts
    │   └── cert.pem
    ├── tlscacerts
    │   └── tls-localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    └── user
```